# Error with php code using while loop?

Tags: php, while-loop

I'm sure I've made an embarrassing error but I can't spot it. I have the following php code which should work as far I can see. However when I print `$minute[19]` for example I get a notice in the browser saying the index is undefined.

Incidentally the only recognized index appears to be `[0]`.

```
$getdata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM visitors ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 20");

$datetime = array();
$time = array();
$parsed = array();
$hour = array();
$minute = array();
$second = array();

$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($getdata);

$i = 0;

while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($getdata))
{
    $datetime[$i] = $result['datetime'];
    $time[$i]= $datetime[$i];
    $parsed[$i] = date_parse($time[$i]);
    $hour[$i] = $parsed[$i]['hour'];
    $minute[$i] = $parsed[$i]['minute'];
    $second[$i] = $parsed[$i]['second'];
}
$i++;
```

for example

```
print_r($minute[19]); // this isn't working
```

Comment: you're incrementing `$i` *outside* the loop...

Comment: @OneTrickPony no need to increment here i guess

Comment: @OneTrickPony also they're assuming they'll have 20 results, which limit only limits the maximum.

Comment: @Odi...you've shed some light on the problem.  The array contains only 19 elements seemingly...from 0 to 18.  Can't understand why as i wanted 20 in the mysql query

Comment: @OneTrickPony the alteration didn't work as suggested below.  Moreover i've had the same set up working before with a while loop

Comment: @OneTrickPony I meant upon reading the array, the poster is assuming that index is filled.

Comment: @Hector this may seem a stupid question - but there are 20 elements in your database - right?

Comment: @Matthew yeah, I think that's another error in the code above :)

Comment: @Spontifixus yeah over 70 in fact.  Not that it should matter but ORDER BY DESC is from most recent id towards right?  So 70id to 50id for example

Comment: @Hector see my updated answer - I think I found the cause...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two places where you fetch the result. One in line 10 of your example:

```
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($getdata);
```

and one in line 14:

```
while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($getdata))
```

The first record that has been fetched in line 10 is been overridden by the new fetch at the beginning of the while-loop. Thus you seem to receive one record less than expected.

Answer (score 3):

You need to move the increment into the loop:

```
$getdata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM visitors ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 20");

$datetime = array();
$time = array();
$parsed = array();
$hour = array();
$minute = array();
$second = array();

$i = 0;

while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($getdata))
{
    $datetime[$i] = $result['datetime'];
    $time[$i]= $datetime[$i];
    $parsed[$i] = date_parse($time[$i]);
    $hour[$i] = $parsed[$i]['hour'];
    $minute[$i] = $parsed[$i]['minute'];
    $second[$i] = $parsed[$i]['second'];
    $i++;
}
```

You could also do without the variable entirely... Something like:

```
$getdata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM visitors ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 20");

$hour = array();
$minute = array();
$second = array();

while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($getdata))
{
    $parsed = date_parse($result['datetime']);
    $hour[] = $parsed['hour'];
    $minute[] = $parsed['minute'];
    $second[] = $parsed['second'];
}
```

Comment: You were right.  I tried it with $minute[18] and it returned a value.  I can't understand why 19 doesn't work when the limit was set to 20 though...odd

Comment: There might be less results in the database than your set limit?

Answer (score 0):

You should add that $i++; into the loop not outside of it :) However I would not suggest using this approach maybe you should explain why you need certain keys out of such an array and then people can help you better.

Comment: Didn't work.  I didn't do it originally because i've had the same set up working before on a different project.